# Java's Bigdecimal.divide and rounding

Tags: java, bigdecimal

At work, we found a problem when trying to divide a large number by 1000. This number came from the database.

Say I have this method:

```
private static BigDecimal divideBy1000(BigDecimal dividendo) {
    if (dividendo == null) return null;

    return dividendo.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(1000), RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
}
```

When I make the following call

```
divideBy1000(new BigDecimal("176100000"))
```

I receive the expected value of 176100. But if I try the line below

```
divideBy1000(new BigDecimal("1761e+5"))
```

I receive the value 200000. Why this occurs? Both numbers are the same with different representation and the latest is what I receive from database. I understand that, somehow, the JVM is dividing the number 1761 by 1000, rounding up and filling with 0's at the end.

What is the best way to avoid this kind of behavior? Keep in mind that the original number is not controlled by me.

Comment: Why do you get a BigDecimal from the database as a String rather than as a BigDecimal in the first place? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBigDecimal%28int%29

Comment: I don't. That was my way to simplify the example here. The original code uses getBigDecimal method.

Comment: Then where in your real code do you have the problem of transforming the string "1761e+5" to a BigDecimal? What is the *actual* problem in your *actual* code?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As specified in javadoc, a `BigDecimal` is defined by an integer value and a **scale**.

> The value of the number represented by the BigDecimal is therefore
>   (unscaledValue × 10^(-scale)).

So `BigDecimal("1761e+5")` has scale -5 and `BigDecimal(176100000)` has scale 0.

The division of the two `BigDecimal` is done using the -5 and 0 scales respectively because the scales are not specified when dividing. The [`divide` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide%28java.math.BigDecimal%29) explains why the results are different.

> **`divide`**
>
> ```
> public BigDecimal divide(BigDecimal divisor)
> ```
>
> Returns a [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) whose value is `(this / divisor)`, and whose preferred scale is `(this.scale() - divisor.scale())`; if the exact quotient cannot be represented (because it has a non-terminating decimal expansion) an `ArithmeticException` is thrown.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> `divisor` - value by which this BigDecimal is to be divided.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> ```
> this / divisor
> ```
>
> **Throws:**
>
> [`ArithmeticException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) — if the exact quotient does not have a terminating decimal expansion
>
> **Since:**
>
> 1.5

If you specify a scale when dividing, e.g. `dividendo.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(1000), 0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)` you will get the same result.

Comment: I was in the middle of typing it, but wanted to triple check my facts.  +1, this is the right answer.

Comment: Thank you! I tried here in my "toy project" and worked. That was exactly the answer I wanted.

Answer (score 7):

The expressions `new BigDecimal("176100000")` and `new BigDecimal("1761e+5")` are **not equal**. `BigDecimal` keeps track of both value, and precision.

`BigDecimal("176100000")` has 9 digits of precision and is represented internally as the `BigInteger("176100000")`, multiplied by 1. `BigDecimal("1761e+5")` has 4 digits of precision and is represented internally as the `BigInteger("1761")`, multiplied by 100000.

When you a divide a `BigDecimal` by a value, the result respects the digits of precision, resulting in different outputs for seemingly equal values.

Comment: That's not true. Use `compareTo` to see that they compare equivalently.  Further, [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=176100000+%3D%3D+1761e%2B5) supports their equality.

Comment: @Makoto: `compareTo` and `equals` are not the same operation for `BigDecimal`.

Comment: I understand that. But how can I avoid this behavior as the number with less precision came from the database? Which is the best way to divide a number that came from the database?

Answer (score 6):

for your division with BigDecimal.

```
dividendo.divide(divisor,2,RoundingMode.CEILING)//00.00 nothing for up and nothing for down
```

in this operation have a precision for two decimals.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid this kind of problems in Java when dividing by powers of 10 you have a much efficient and precise approach:

```
dividendo.movePointLeft(3)
```

Comment: and of course the corresponding movePointRight

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's kind of issue what you're experimenting. If I may, in a situation where you only have exponental numbers, you should cast them and then use your method. See what I suggest is this bit of code down there:

```
long  longValue = Double.valueOf("1761e+5").longValue();
BigDecimal value= new BigDecimal(longValue);
```

Use it in a method which would convert those string into a new BigDecimal and return this BigDecimal value. Then you can use those returned values with divideBy1000.That should clear any issue you're having.

If you have a lot of those, what you can do also in store those BigDecimal in a data structure like a list. Then use a foreach loop in which you apply divideBy1000 and each new value would be stored in a different list. Then you would just have to access this list to have your new set of values !

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This should give what it is you're looking for I think @RaphaeldoVale

Answer (score 0):

Try using `round()`.

```
private static BigDecimal divideBy1000(BigDecimal dividendo) {
    if (dividendo == null) return null;

    return dividendo.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(1000)).round(new MathContext(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
}

 public static void main(String []args){
    BigDecimal bigD = new BigDecimal("1761e5");
    BigDecimal bigDr = divideBy1000(bigD);
    System.out.println(bigDr);
 }
```

The `new MathContext(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP))` line returns the division to 4 places.

This produces:

```
1.761E+5
```

Which is what you want. (:

Comment: Why would one need to round to get **more** precision?

Comment: I didn't downvote.  But your answer doesn't explain why this appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you are multiplying a BigDecimal by a power of 10, in this case you are multiplying by 10<sup>-3</sup>, you can use `dividendo.scaleByPowerOfTen(power)` which only modifies the scale of the BigDecimal object and side steps any rounding issues, or at least moves them to a later calculation.

The other answers here cover the more general case of dividing by any number.

Answer (score 0):

I want to quote basic concepts for `BigDecimal`:

> A `BigDecimal` consists of an arbitrary precision integer unscaled value and a 32-bit integer scale.

```java
public class BigDecimal extends Number implements Comparable<BigDecimal> {
    // …
    private final BigInteger intVal;
    private final int scale;
}
```

- That is, `BigDecimal` number is represented as `unscaled integer value * 10^(-scale)`
- For example, `1.234 = 1234 * 10^(-3)`. So, precision is `4`, scale is `3`.
- Please refer to basic concept in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35436935/9304999).

For the former:

```java
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal("176100000");
System.out.println(bd1.precision());  // 9
System.out.println(bd1.scale());      // 0

BigDecimal bd2 = BigDecimal.valueOf(1000);
System.out.println(bd2.precision());  // 4
System.out.println(bd2.scale());      // 0

System.out.println(bd1.divide(bd2));                        // 176100
System.out.println(bd1.divide(bd2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));  // 176100

BigDecimal result = bd1.divide(bd2);
System.out.println(result.precision());  // 6
System.out.println(result.scale());      // 0
```

1. The `new BigDecimal("176100000")`'s precision is `9` and scale is `0`.
2. The `BigDecimal.valueOf(1000)`'s precision is `4` and scale is `0`.
3. `(176100000 * 10^0) / (1000 * 10^0) = 176100 * 10^0`.
4. With method `public BigDecimal divide​(BigDecimal divisor, RoundingMode roundingMode)`, we have to use the dividend(`new BigDecimal("176100000")`)'s scale as a scale of returning `BigDecimal`. In this case, the scale is `0`.

   > Returns a `BigDecimal` whose value is (this / divisor), and whose **scale is this.scale()**.
5. As a result, we have `BigDecimal` number `176100 * 10^0` whose precision is `6` and scale is `0`.
6. The rounding is applied, but the result is integer already, so we just get `176100`.

For the latter:

```java
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal("1761e+5");
System.out.println(bd1.precision());  // 4
System.out.println(bd1.scale());      // -5

BigDecimal bd2 = BigDecimal.valueOf(1000);
System.out.println(bd2.precision());  // 4
System.out.println(bd2.scale());      // 0

System.out.println(bd1.divide(bd2));                        // 1.761E+5
System.out.println(bd1.divide(bd2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));  // 2E+5

BigDecimal result1 = bd1.divide(bd2);
System.out.println(result1.precision());  // 4
System.out.println(result1.scale());      // -2

BigDecimal result2 = bd1.divide(bd2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println(result2.precision());  // 1
System.out.println(result2.scale());      // -5
```

1. The `new BigDecimal("1761e+5")`'s precision is `4` and scale is `-5`.
2. The `BigDecimal.valueOf(1000)`'s precision is `4` and scale is `0`.
3. `(1761 * 10^(-(-5))) / (1000 * 10^0) = 1.761 * 10^(-(-5))`
4. `= 1761 * 10^(-(-2))` whose precision is `4` and scale is `-2`; prints `"1.761E+5"` using scientific notation of overriden `toString`.
5. If we apply rounding, `1.761 * 10^(-(-5)) = 2 * 10^(-(-5))` whose precision is `1` and scale is `-5`; prints `"2E+5"` using scientific notation of overriden `toString`.

---

I am might be wrong. If you could catch my mistakes, please comment to this answer. I'll correct them.