# BigDecimal, precision and scale

Tags: java, jpa, scale, precision, bigdecimal

I'm using BigDecimal for my numbers in my application, for example, with JPA. I did a bit of researching about the terms 'precision' and 'scale' but I don't understand what are they exactly.

Can anyone explain me the meaning of 'precision' and 'scale' for a BigDecimal value?

```
@Column(precision = 11, scale = 2)
```

Thanks!

Comment: The question has got absolutely nothing to with `java.math.BigDecimal`. `@javax.persistence.Column` is not part of Java SE. It is the subject of JPA.

Comment: Precision and scale are terms often used for java.math.BigDecimal, which is what he uses for calculations, for example with JPA. ISTM he or she wants to know what they mean in the context of BigDecimal alright.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

A `BigDecimal` is defined by two values: an arbitrary precision integer and a 32-bit integer *scale*. The value of the `BigDecimal` is defined to be [image: unscaledValue*10^{-scale}].

**Precision:**

> The [precision](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#precision()) is the number of digits in the unscaled value.
> For instance, for the number 123.45, the precision returned is 5.

So, *precision* indicates the length of the arbitrary precision integer. Here are a few examples of numbers with the same scale, but different precision:

- 12345 / 100000 = 0.12345 // scale = 5, precision = 5
- 12340 / 100000 = 0.1234  // scale = 4, precision = 4
- 1 / 100000 = 0.00001     // scale = 5, precision = 1

In the special case that the number is equal to zero (i.e. 0.000), the precision is always 1.

**Scale:**

> If zero or positive, the [scale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#scale()) is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point. If negative, the unscaled value of the number is multiplied by ten to the power of the negation of the scale. For example, a scale of -3 means the unscaled value is multiplied by 1000.

This means that the integer value of the ‘BigDecimal’ is multiplied by [image: 10^{-scale}].

Here are a few examples of the same precision, with different scales:

- 12345 with scale 5 = 0.12345
- 12345 with scale 4 = 1.2345
- …
- 12345 with scale 0 = 12345
- 12345 with scale -1 = 123450 *†*

**BigDecimal.toString:**

The `toString` method for a `BigDecimal` behaves differently based on the scale and `precision`. (Thanks to @RudyVelthuis for pointing this out.)

- If `scale == 0`, the integer is just printed out, as-is.
- If `scale < 0`, E-Notation is always used (e.g. 5 scale -1 produces "5E+1")
- If `scale >= 0` and `precision - scale -1 >= -6` a plain decimal number is produced (e.g. 10000000 scale 1 produces "1000000.0")
- Otherwise,  E-notation is used, e.g. 10 scale 8 produces "1.0E-7" since `precision - scale -1` equals [image: unscaledValue*10^{-scale}] is less than -6.

**More examples:**

- 19/100 = 0.19 // integer=19, scale=2, precision=2
- 1/1000 = 0.0001 // integer=1, scale = 4, precision = 1

Comment: Actually, `[12345, -1]` is better represented by `1.2345E+5`, which is probably what `ToString` will return, too. Otherwise, very nice explanation.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Thanks, I added a section explaining how the toString method determines whethe or not to use E+ notation

Comment: Heck, I see I wrote `ToString`. That is Delphi speak, not Java. ;-)

Comment: 0.12345 - this is six digits total, not five

Comment: @jarosik 0.12345 has scale of 5 because there are 5 digits to the right of the decimal point. That there are six digits displayed doesn't necessarily matter.

Comment: Your example and reference contradict each other: Reference reads as `If zero or positive, the scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point` but in your example, you wrote `0.12345 // scale = 5` and `0.1234 // scale = 5`

Comment: @Farid, `0.1234` is mathematically equivalent to `0.12340`.

Comment: why the scale is not 4 below?
12340 / 100000 = 0.1234 // scale = 5, precision = 4

Comment: When I do `println(BigDecimal(12345).setScale(2))` then result is 12345.00 and not 0.12345 as mentioned in the answer

Comment: @firstpostcommenter I'm not sure where the answer mentions 12345.00 versus 0.12345, but I suggest you check the JavaDocs on what *exactly* `setScale()` is doing: It returns a BigDecimal whose scale is the specified value, and whose value is numerically equal to this BigDecimal's. So, if `bd` is a BigDecimal, then `bd.equals(bd.setScale(2))` is `true`.

Answer (score 90):

- **Precision:**  Total number of significant digits
- **Scale:** Number of digits to the right of the decimal point

See [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class documentation for details.

Answer (score 6):

Precision is the total number of significant digits in a number.
Scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point.

Examples:

123.456 Precision=6 Scale=3

10 Precision=2 Scale=0

-96.9923 Precision=6 Scale=4

0.0 Precision=1 Scale=1

Negative Scale

For a negative scale value, we apply the following formula:
result = (given number) * 10 ^ (-(scale value))
Example

Given number = 1234.56

scale = -5

->  (1234.56) * 10^(-(-5))

->  (1234.56) * 10^(+5)

->  123456000

Reference: https://www.logicbig.com/quick-info/programming/precision-and-scale.html

Answer (score 4):

Quoting [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#precision()):

> The precision is the number of digits in the unscaled value.

and

> If zero or positive, the scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point. If negative, the unscaled value of the number is multiplied by ten to the power of the negation of the scale. For example, a scale of -3 means the unscaled value is multiplied by 1000.

Answer (score 3):

From your example annotation the maximum digits is 2 after the decimal point and 9 before (totally 11):
`123456789,01`

Answer (score 0):

The JPA annotation `@Column(precision = 11, scale = 2)` for `BigDecimal` variable translates to `DECIMAL(11,2)` in the MYSQL database.

This means, the column can store a value having 11 digits in total, with 2 digits allowed after the decimal. ie. the Range here would be `[-999999999.99,999999999.99]`