# BigDecimal divide with scale

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have

```
private static final BigDecimal ONE_HUNDRED = new BigDecimal(100);
    private static final BigDecimal TEN = new BigDecimal(10);
```

`BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(1050);` 
I need to get 10% I write 
`BigDecimal decimalResult = decimal.divide(ONE_HUNDRED).multiply(TEN)//100, 10`

But Intellij IDE says:

> 'BigDecimal.divide()' called without a rounding mode argument more...

I added `BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP` and all others but I get wrong result. I need `1050/100 = 10.5`  but if I add `BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP` result = `11`.

How can I correctly divide with scale parameters?

Comment: maybe you should read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35435691/bigdecimal-precision-and-scale

Comment: What are `ONE_HUNDRED` and `TEN`?

Comment: `TEN` and `ONE_HUNDRED` does not exists as constants in `BigDecimal`

Comment: Define 'more ...'.

Comment: As in my answer, you could specify the scale during creation of `BigDecimal`

Comment: I faund solution. BigDecimal recovery = amount.divide(ONE_HUNDRED, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP) But @ freedev  - Why TEN and ONE_HUNDRED does not exists as constants in BigDecimal? I created constans myself

Comment: @user5620472 Good solution. Note that freedev commented prior to your edit: in the previous version you didn't show what TEN and ONE_HUNDRED were. By the way, TEN _is_ defined in BigDecimal and therefore you don't need to define it yourself. Also, it's better to write `BigDecimal.valueOf(x)` than `new BigDecimal(x)`.

Comment: Please, note that for a good result, you should always multiply before you divide, even with BigDecimals. But IntelliJ is simply wrong. You *can* use `divide()` without a rounding mode. You just risk an error if the result would have to create a non-terminating repetitive fraction, but that is rather unlikely if you divide by 100. Dividing by 3 would give you an error, if you don't give a rounding mode.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis IntelliJ is not wrong. It doesn't give you an error; it's just a friendly warning because calling `divide()` without supplying a rounding mode is a common cause of logic error, usually due to failure to think properly about rounding. If you know what you are doing and are deliberately calling `divide()` without a rounding mode, you can then safely ignore the warning or turn it off.

Answer (score 16):

```
public static double divide(double d1, double d2) {
    BigDecimal b1 = new BigDecimal(d1);
    BigDecimal b2 = new BigDecimal(d2);
    return b1.divide(b2, 2, RoundingMode.DOWN).doubleValue();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This example returns `105.0000`

```
public class TestBigDecimal {
  static BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(1050).setScale(4, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
  static BigDecimal ONE_HUNDRED = new BigDecimal(100);
  static BigDecimal TEN = new BigDecimal(10);

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    BigDecimal decimalResult = decimal.divide(ONE_HUNDRED).multiply(TEN) ;
    System.out.println(decimalResult);
  }
}
```

You should adjust the scale during the creation of `decimal` variable.

Comment: Intellij IDE is still saying: "'BigDecimal.divide()' called without a rounding mode argument more..." I don't think your answer answers the question

Comment: You know, TEN already exists as a constant in the `BigDecimal` class.

Comment: @RC right, I think this answer should fit the problem.

Comment: What exactly does IntelliJ say? what is the text *after* the `more...`part? Because you *can* use `divide()` without a rounding mode, and it is entirely safe if you use ONE_HUNDRED as argument.